# R API Connection (Localytics) with getURL and RCurl Error

Tags: r, api, ssl, parameters, rcurl

I am trying to get data from the mobile analytics service Localytics via their API (https://api.localytics.com/docs#query). In particular I would like to translate the following cURL command in R:

```
curl --get  'https://api.localytics.com/v1/query' \
 --user 'API_KEY:API_SECRET' \
 --data 'app_id=APP_ID' \
 --data 'metrics=users' \
 --data 'dimensions=day' \
 --data-urlencode 'conditions={"day":["between","2013-04-01","2013-04-07"]}'
```

My R code looks like this at the moment. APIKey and API secret are of course replaced by the actual keys. However, I receive an error stating that at least a dimension or a metric has to be specified.

```
object <- getURL('https://api.localytics.com/v1/query', userpwd = "API_Key:API_Secret", httpheader=list(app_id = "app_id=03343434353534",
metrics = "metrics=users",
dimensions = "dimensions=day",
conditions = toJSON('conditions={"day":["between","2014-07-01","2014-07-10"]}')),  ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

What changes would be necessary to get it to work.

Thanks in advance for helping me out,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

This is particular easy with the dev version of httr:

```
library(httr)

r <- POST('https://api.localytics.com/v1/query',  
  body = list(
    app_id = "APP_ID",
    metrics = "users",
    dimensions = "day",
    conditions = list(
      day = c("between", "2014-07-01", "2004-07-10")
    )
  ), 
  encode = "json",
  authenticate("API_key", "API_secret")
)
stop_for_status(r)
content(r)
```

(I converted the request to a POST and used json encoding for everything, as describe in the API docs).

If you want to see exactly what's being sent to the server, use the `verbose()` config.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `getURL` passes the parameters you quested as HTTP headers and not as querystring data as your `curl` call does. You should use `getForm` instead. Also, I wasn't sure from which library your `toJSON` function came form, but that's at least not the right syntax for the one from `rsjon`.

Anyway, here's a call from R which should produce the same HTTP call are your `curl` command

```
library(rjson)
library(RCurl)
object <- getForm('https://api.localytics.com/v1/query',  
    app_id = "APP_ID",
    metrics = "users",
    dimensions = "day",
    conditions = toJSON(list(day=c("between","2014-07-01","2004-07-10"))),  
    .opts=curlOptions(
        userpwd = "API_Key:API_Secret",  httpauth = 1L)
)
```

I found that using the site http://requestb.in/ is very helpful in debugging these problems (and that's exactly what I used to create this solution). You can send requests to their site and they record the exact HTTP message that was sent so you can compare different methods.

The `httpauth` part was from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157969/rcurl-http-authentication-when-site-responds-with-http-401-code-without-www-aut) which seemed to be required to trigger authentication for the test site; you may not need it for the "real" site.

Comment: It's a really really really bad idea to use `ssl.verifypeer = FALSE`.

Comment: Good to know. I was just trying to adjust the OP's code. I wasn't sure why it was in there originally and didn't want to take it out just in case.

Comment: You should always take it out!