# R scrape bitbucket with authentication

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

I'd like to retrieve all the URLS for the different repositories inside an internal bitbucket project.

The list of urls is present on `https://bitbucket.mycompany.be/projects/myproject`

I am apparently able to `GET` the page using

```
r <- GET(myurl, 
         verbose(), 
         authenticate(user = "myID", password = "myPW", type = "basic"))
```

However, the content just shows me the info about the project itself, not the repos included. any help to het the full page?

```
content(r, "text")
[1] "{\"key\":\"myproject\",\"id\":398,\"name\":\"myproject",\"public\":false,\"type\":\"NORMAL\",\"links\":{\"self\":[{\"href\":\"https://myurl"}]}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed using the [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10162987/5224236):

```
getURL(myurl, userpwd="myID:myPW.", httpauth = 1L) %>% html_text()
```